# Cannot read SMS in reading mode Android 5.0?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-5.0-lollipop, android-sms

I have an SMS incoming phone number `123456`. I want to use an Intent to open the SMS message of the incoming phone number in the service. I tried two ways, but they give unsatisfied results

First way:

```
        Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        smsIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
        smsIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(smsIntent);
```

The way only opens the SMS list. We have to look at the incoming phone in the list and requires one more step to open the content of incoming SMS phone. I want to ignore the step. It means it will directly go the content of the incoming SMS phone number.

Second way:

```
        Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
        smsIntent.putExtra("address", SMSphoneNumber);
        smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body",SMSBody);
        smsIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(smsIntent);
```

This way can read the detail of incoming SMS phone number but it is in sending mode. I want to read SMS in reading mode.

How can I do it in Android L? Thank all

The question is related with [How to open SMS intent to read (not send) message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39678042/how-to-open-sms-intent-to-read-not-send-message). The different one is providing the source code for two cases: one is reading mode (first one) with requiring one more step, another one is sending mode.

Update: This is way what I get the SMS incoming phone number

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
                    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
                    SmsMessage[] smgs = null;
                    String infoSender = "";
                    String infoSMS = "";

                    if (extras != null) {
                        // Retrieve the sms message received
                        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) extras.get("pdus");
                        smgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

                        for (int i = 0; i < smgs.length; i++) {
                            smgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                            infoSender += smgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                            if (smgs[i].getMessageBody()!=null)
                                infoSMS += smgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                            else
                                infoSMS += ".";
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Phone in SMSReceiver is -" + infoSender + "Body is" + infoSMS, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
        }
    } 

}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. do you want to get the number and message body and filter it for a specific number ?

Comment: I already have number and body from BroadcastReceiver. I just want to open the SMS of the incoming phone number in reading mode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open SMS intent to read (not send) message?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39678042/how-to-open-sms-intent-to-read-not-send-message)

Comment: I asked the question but I did not found the answer yet. So I made the new question to make more clear what i need, instead of update it

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open the message in the default application then you will be needing the thread id of the message you received. What you can do is query the message db and get the thread id using your logic and then open it using the below intent -

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

intent.setData(Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations/" + sms.getThreadId()));
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: sms is a custom object which stores the thread id. In your case you have to query the db and get the thread id of the latest message. You need to develop your logic for that.

Comment: I got thread id from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30260877/restore-sms-create-thread-if-not-exists, however, the result is similar my second way. It went to sending mode, instead of reading mode

Comment: result will be similar if that thread id doesn't exist. If its already in the db then it will open up the view where you can read the message

Comment: Do you have any link to get thread id of incoming SMS. I will show the SMS Broadcast in my update question

Comment: you can't get the thread id from the broadcast receiver. You have to query the message db itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124207/discussion-between-user8430-and-gautam).

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer with support from @Gautam. 
First, we have to get `thread_id` of an SMS by using the code

```
 public static long getThreadId(Context context, String phoneNumber) {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, "thread_id IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY (thread_id AND address=?", new String[]{phoneNumber}, "date DESC");
        long threadId=0;
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            threadId = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("thread_id"));
        }
        cursor.close();
        return threadId;
    }
```

From `thread_id`, we can show SMS content in reading mode as follows:

```
        long thread_id=  getThreadId(getApplicationContext(), SMSphoneNumber);
        Log.d(TAG,"==========THREAD ID"+String.valueOf(thread_id)+"=========");
        smsIntent.setData(Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations/" + thread_id));
        smsIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        getApplicationContext().startActivity(smsIntent);
```

Hope it help someone